# can one cluster IIS- WAS for TCP/IP clustering or is it HTTP only

Tags: iis, nlb

Does the NLB (network load balancing) feature of IIS extend to an ability to cluster TCP/IP traffic using WAS (Windows Process Activation Service)?  I could certainly use HTTP to host WCF services but would prefer the efficiency of a TCP/IP binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what it is you're asking but here goes:

1. NLB is a component of Windows, not IIS.
2. NLB works at the network layer. You can create NLB port rules to load balance TCP and\or UDP traffic on any port or port range.
3. NLB is not "application aware". It has no knowledge of anything above layer 3. It doesn't know or care about WAS, WCF, or HTTP. It only load balances traffic based on the port rules you create. It does not load balance based on application load, CPU or memory load, etc.

Comment: Correcting my question provided the answer.  Thanks, that is exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Glad to help...